# Program For Hearing My Sound Live?

Tags: windows, software-rec, audio

Is there any software which do this job for me :

I want  to  speak in  a microphone by hearing my sound synchronous from PC speakers.

Is there any program to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows 7, you can do following steps:

1. Right click the sound speaker in the bottom right, choose "Recording devices".
2. In the window, double click the correct device.
3. go to "listen" tab and check the box reading "listen to this device".

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Sound Drivers incorporate a Loop back in their default settings it's often on the Recording Tab of the Sound Control panel it's sometimes referred to as "Listen to this device". There you can route the microphone to the local PC Speakers.

If you need software specifically you might want to try something like this. 
http://download.cnet.com/Microphone-Pass-through-Emulator/3000-18503_4-10973610.html

Good Luck. 
JW

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7: Right click the sound speaker in the bottom right, choose "Recording devices". In the window, double click the correct device, then go into the second tab (I think). There has to be something like "Use this recording device as a playback source". This will return your mic directly to the speakers.

For Windows XP your sound driver has to provide some sort of "microphone playback device" which should be in the "playback device" list in your "speaker icon".